# Copy a range of files in command line (ZSH/BASH)

Tags: linux, bash, copy, zsh

I have a list of files with consecutive numbers as suffixes. I would like to copy only a range of these files. How can I specify a range as part of my cp command.

```
$ls
P1080272.JPG* P1080273.JPG* P1080274.JPG* P1080275.JPG* P1080276.JPG* P1080277.JPG*
P1080278.JPG* P1080279.JPG* P1080280.JPG* P1080281.JPG* P1080282.JPG* P1080283.JPG*
```

I would like to copy files from P1080275.JPG to P1080283.JPG with something similar to:

```
$cp P10802[75-83].JPG ~/Images/.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You were very close. Your question was almost the correct syntax:

```
cp P10802{75..83}.JPG ~/Images
```

Answer (score 9):

To iterate over a range in bash:

```
for x in {0..10}; do echo $x; done
```

Applying the same in your case:

```
for x in {272..283}; do cp P1080$x.JPG ~/Images; done
```

Comment: This does work, but I like @glenn jackman's answer better since it doesn't invoke any programming construct.

Answer (score 4):

Zsh, with the extendedglob option has the  *globbing* (pattern matching) operator.

```
setopt extendedglob
echo P10802<75-83>.JPG
```

will match filenames in the current directory that match that pattern (beware that P1080275.JPG matches but so does P108020000000075.JPG)

On the other end, the {x...y} string expansion operator (supported by zsh and recent versions of bash and ksh93), expands to the strings from x to y, regardless of what files there are in the current directory.

```
cp P10802<75-83>.JPG ~there
```

will copy the matching files, so will

```
cp P10802{75..83}.JPG ~there
```

But you'll get errors if for instance P1080281.JPG doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you:

```
for each in {75..83}; do cp P10802$each.JPG ~/Images/; done
```